# WPF Editable ComboBox incremental search

Tags: c#, events, combobox, observablecollection, increment

I have a Question about Combobox in WPF (C#) and incremental search. Maybe someone has a good idea how can i solve my Problem.

I have in my application an ObservableCollectin with all zip-codes and Citys in Switzerland. So this Collection has round 3500 Items. Now I tried to use a Combobox where i can start type my zip-code and after to letters the Popup will Show with this elements from the Collection. This filter a can make with Lampda, thats easy.
My Problem is the Event from the Combobox. I tried with PreviewTextInput, but there a got everytime when the Events fired only one Letter and not the hole entred text. The other Problem by this solution is, that everytime where I load the new Collection to the ItemsSource, the market text in the TextEdit field changed to the new selectedItem.

I work now since 5 days on it, and maybe I can't see the forrest for the trees. So if someone has a good idea, pleas answer.

Thanks and a Nice day.

Answer (score 3):

I think this could help you : http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/11/12/5088649.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this Tipp. I tried out, and have build my own Combobox-Control with it. This works fine for me.

Comment: The link is unfortunately outdated.

Comment: Here is a working link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150820071000/http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/5088649